# Como criar um arquivo se o mesmo não existe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, eu estou fazendo um aplicativo que irá ter dados em JSON e gostaria de saber, como criar um arquivo se ele não existe? Estou usando o FS.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No node, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const file = "/home/user/Documents/foo.json";

if (!fs.existsSync(file)) {
    fs.writeFileSync(file, JSON.stringify({hello: "World"));
}
```

O script verifica e o arquivo existe e, do contrário, cria com um objeto ilustrativo.